# Ubuntu 16.04 install on SD card giving boot error: no such device. grub rescue>

Tags: grub2, partitioning, grubrescue

I managed to install Ubuntu 16.04.2 on a 32gb SD card plugged into an Asus x205ta. I made three partitions- one mounted at /, one mounted at /home, and swap space. When I try to boot, I get
Error: No such device (long number sequence)
entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
I have searched the forums for answers, but none have worked. Boot Repair gave an error. Did I partition the disk correctly? Do I need to reinstall Grub2?

Comment: Have you set your sd card as first boot device in the boot priority list in BIOS?

Comment: yes i tried that, all it does is change the position of the error message to the center of the screen

Comment: You should try to boot from USB-cardreader/writer with SD-card inserted into it. Internal may require additional drivers.

Comment: Any idea about where I might get additional drivers? I don't have access to a usb reader/writer.